# Spring security: Multiple times login url shows up

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have following spring security configuration:-

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/footer").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/index").authenticated()
        .anyRequest().permitAll()

        .and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.html")

        .and().rememberMe().tokenValiditySeconds(2419200)  //valid for 4 weeks

        .and().httpBasic();

    //.and()
        //.requiresChannel()
            //.antMatchers("/").requiresSecure();
}
```

When I hit url "/index", I see a login screen which is correct.

After I am logged in, when I change URL in browser to "/footer", I again see a login screen. But I already logged-in earlier, so is this behavior normal?

My requirement is that both login page and footer page need to be authenticated. If user, goes to footer page before login, then he should be promted for authentication.
If he already is authentication, then the page should be displayed to him.

Answer (score 0):

change the matchers like this, and it will work as per your need.

```
http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/footer", "/index").authenticated()
            //.antMatchers("/footer", "/index").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")  by this you can allow a particular role to access this url
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login.html")
            .and().rememberMe().tokenValiditySeconds(2419200) //valid for 4 weeks
            .and().httpBasic();
```

here you can use commented line at the place of authenticated().

Comment: This will make footer page accessible to everyone without login. I don't want that.

Comment: at the place of permitAll(), use this hasAnyRole([role1,role2])  in access().
and other then this, 
use this
.antMatchers("/footer", "/index").authenticated()

Comment: If I replace anyRequest().permitAll() by anyRequest().hasAnyRole(), then there are more problems like infinite redirects to login page.

Comment: I have update my answer, if you still have any concern please provide me source by which I could understand what exactly your facing, because its working in all cases which I generated.

Answer (score 0):

Just put antMatchers("/footer", "/index").authenticated(). This matches with your requirements.

Comment: Even this does not help. It makes no difference.